# Multiple click listeners on buttons

Tags: java, android, button, onclick, kotlin

I want to know how to add multiple click events to buttons defined in XML, as previously, in Java, we implemented `View.onClickListener` interface and did the rest of the work in `onClick` method.
Example:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.oneButton:
        // do your code
        break;

    case R.id.twoButton:
        // do your code
        break;

    case R.id.threeButton:
        // do your code
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

I'm making a basic calculator app with the new Kotlin but it seems Kotlin has no such provisions, instead my code looks too long and verbose, as I'm attaching events to all buttons individually.
Can someone tell me how to do the same way in Kotlin? Thanks

Comment: You can try to copy this code to Android Studio and see what you get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all implement `OnClickListener` in your `Activity`, like

```
class MainActivity : Activity , OnClickListener
```

then override its implementation like

```
func onClick(v:View) {  
   //use when here like
   case R.id.youview -> {
   // do your work on click of view
    }
```

Don't forgot to set clicklistener on your `View`.

```
  yourView.setOnClickListener(this)
```

Or for better understanding go step by step -

1. Implement `OnClickListener` in your `Activity`.
2. Compiler will ask you to implement overrided methods. Implement those.
3. Copy paste your java code which you wrote inside `onClick` method, that can be converted by kotlin itself or write down `when` conditions.

Comment: in java we do something like - `case R.id.oneButton:
        case R.id.twoButton:
        // do your code
        break;` when we have two different buttons for same task, how can we achieve this in kotlin??

Comment: ohk, i found the way to do the same in kotlin, `case R.id.oneButton, case R.id.twoButton ->` and it's done...

Answer (score 10):

For multiple onClickListeners in `kotlin` `(version:1.1.60)`, the following helped me. Hope it'll be useful to someone else too.

Implement `OnClickListener` to activity like:

```
class YourActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener
```

set your button in `onCreate()`:

```
val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonId)
```

and assign `onclick` to the button in `onCreate()`:

```
button.setOnClickListener { onClick(button) }
```

and in the override method of `onClick()` :

```
 override fun onClick(v: View) {
    when (v.id) {
        R.id.buttonId -> { //your code  }
        ..
        ..
        ..
        else -> { //your code  }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, in Kotlin you can do it like this:

```
view.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when(v?.id) {
            R.id.imgBack -> {/* do your code */}
            R.id.twoButton -> {/* do your code */}
            R.id.threeButton -> {/* do your code */}
            else -> {/* do your code */}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried but the view object can't be cast to Button. Can you post the full code where the view object was declared? Thanks

Comment: This seems the most "kotlinish," but the code won't compile.  The `when` statement needs to handle the nullable with !!. or ?.  In my case I chose to throw an exception, so that line should be `when(v!!.id) {`

Comment: @SMBiggs oh yes, you're right. Just realize it. You can add a null checker for the v, like `when(v?.id) {`. I've updated the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can try this following code:

```
class Testing:AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
  private val mButton1:Button
  private val mButton2:Button
  protected fun onCreate(savedInstanceState:Bundle) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_testing)
    mButton1 = findViewById(R.id.btn_click) as Button
    mButton2 = findViewById(R.id.btn_click1) as Button
    mButton1.setOnClickListener(this)
    mButton2.setOnClickListener(this)
  }
  fun onClick(view:View) {
    when (view.getId()) {
      R.id.btn_click -> {
        Toast.makeText(this, "button 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
      }
      R.id.btn_click1 -> {
        Toast.makeText(this, "button 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
      }
      else -> {}
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this is help you.

Comment: In java i'm declaring buttons like this : `Button btn1, btn2;`, how can i declare multiple buttons in single line in kotlin?

Comment: Using this syntax is discouraged, thus some newer languages like *Kotlin don't even allow them*.

Answer (score 2):

This code worked for me:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    imgBack.setOnClickListener(this)
    twoButton.setOnClickListener(this)
    threeButton.setOnClickListener(this)
}

override fun onClick(view:View) {
    when (view.id) {
        R.id.imgBack -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "imgBack", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        R.id.twoButton -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "twoButton", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        else -> {}
    }
}
```

Don't forget implement `View.OnClickListener` in your class.

Answer (score 0):

you can create anonymous object from an inteface View.ClickListener and pass it to setOnClickListener function

```
private val clickListener = View.OnClickListener { p0 ->
    when (p0.id) {
        ....
    }
}

... setOnClickListener(clickListener)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below like this.

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button xyz = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xyz);
        xyz.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { 
    }}
```

More detailed information at https://androidacademic.blogspot.in/2016/12/multiple-buttons-onclicklistener-android.html

Comment: Question asked for Kotlin and you gave the answer in Java.